# PDF file won't display

Tags: php, pdf

So, I've followed a lot of posts here on StackOverflow still can't work out why my code doesn't work.

I want to be able to open a `.pdf` file outside the web root, so I've tried this code:

```
<?php
    $file = '/user/Desktop/exemplo.pdf';
    echo $file.'<br>';
    $filename = 'test.pdf';

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    @readfile($file);
?>
```

Problem is I always get the same error:

```
pdf this file cannot be correctly displayed
```

I've decided to try several browsers: firefox, chrome, opera and finally internet explorer which suprinsingly said something the others didn't:

```
 file does not start with '%pdf-'Local\EWH-696-6
```

So does someone know what I need to configure in my code to open pdf's? Or to have them start with the code above (hardcoding it didn't fix it).

EDIT: tried removing the `echo` and still had the same error.

Comment: remove this line `echo $file.'<br>';`

Comment: PDF still doesn't open.

Comment: Make sure there are no characters before `<?` at the start of your php file. Save the file as plain text without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Also, make sure PHP is actually able to read the file (i.e., does the file exist, and does PHP have read permission?)

Comment: if that path to your pdf is outside the root folder use an absolute path

Comment: You should also try looking at the actual output of your script. For example, type this at the command line: `curl -s http://your-site.example.com/exemplo.pdf | xxd | head`

Comment: is your PDF is valid ?

Comment: I've been carefull about the empty spaces (it would fix some other questions)

that command is exactly what I needed, and you guys are spot on, 404 not found